# Reverse engineering decoder

Tags: java

How would I create an encoder using this decoding function?

```
String value = "yepCock" + Math.log(3.0) / 4.0;

public static String b(String s) {
    byte[] base = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
    char[] result = new char[base.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < base.length; ++i) {
        result[i] = (char)(base[i] ^ value.charAt(i % value.length()));
    }
    return new String(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just performing operations in reverse order, something like:

```java
static String value = "yepCock" + Math.log(3.0) / 4.0;

public static String decode(String s) {
    byte[] base = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
    char[] result = new char[base.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < base.length; ++i) {
        result[i] = (char) (base[i] ^ value.charAt(i % value.length()));
    }
    return new String(result);
}

public static String encode(String s) {
    byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
        b[i] ^= value.charAt(i % value.length());
    }
    return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(b));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(decode(encode("Reverse engineering decoder")));
}
```